# NPE when saving the selected item of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

Why I am getting a NullPointerException at `fn = list.getSelectedItem().toString();`.

```
public class FileList extends Activity{

ListView list;
String fn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.filelist);


    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);

    String pth = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getListOfFiles(pth));
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                     View arg1, int position, long arg3)
         {
            System.out.println(list.getSelectedItem().toString());
             fn = list.getSelectedItem().toString();   //NPE Here
         }
         });

}
```

Comment: theres a typo on line 5 of `getSelectedItem()`.

Comment: @r2DoesInc what? It looks like I am turned blind :D can you please find it for me :P

Comment: Where is fn declared? Please note that you cannot modify the value of variables declared outside of the scope of the OnItemClickListener, and you may only read their values if they are declared `final`

Comment: no, youre not blind, you just dont know how to post relevant info with your question. we have no idea what your code is doing, post your methods!

Comment: @Amit what you want is the item clicked in listview?

Comment: @Raghunandan I just want to save the selected item from my listview to use it somewhere else.

Comment: @Amit follow my post. saving is left to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `getItemAtPosition` instead

```
 String path = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29

Docs:

> public Object getItemAtPosition (int position)
>       Added in API level 1
>
> ```
> Gets the data associated with the specified position in the list.
> Parameters
> position  Which data to get
> Returns The data associated with the specified position in the list
> ```

Also read

> public Object getSelectedItem () Added in API level 1
>
> Returns The data corresponding to the currently selected item, or null
>   if there is nothing selected.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use another approach:

```
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Object selectedValue = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String value = selectedValue.toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen  " + value , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: Just clarify that this way should be used with ListActivity.